# How to sort a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting

Does ANYBODY know how to sort a multidimensional array?! I've been trying to do this for hours, with no success. I'm trying to sort the array "$page" with "position" in ascending order, as that's the position to show in the navigation bar. Any help would be MUCH appreciated! Already tried most of the on examples in the documentation, but nothing seems to work.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [position] => 0
        [text] => Home
        [url] => ./
        [navigation] => true
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [position] => 0
        [text] => 404
        [url] => ./?p=404
        [navigation] => false
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [position] => 0
        [text] => 403
        [url] => ./?p=403
        [navigation] => false
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [position] => 1
        [text] => Posts
        [url] => ./?p=posts
        [navigation] => true
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [position] => 3
        [text] => Users
        [url] => ./?p=users
        [navigation] => true
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [position] => 1
        [text] => Logout
        [url] => ./?p=logout
        [navigation] => false
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [position] => 2
        [text] => Banner
        [url] => ./?p=banner
        [navigation] => true
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [position] => 5
        [text] => Login
        [url] => ./?p=login
        [navigation] => false
    )

)
```

Please don't tell me to search, because I have, and nothing is working! One of them did work when i was testing it locally, but my server threw up an error so I had to find an alternative.

Comment: What was the solution that worked, and what was the error the server threw?

Comment: SO how have you tried to sort it? usort()? array_multisort()? WHat error did you get?

Comment: Have you tried searching, using google for example? .. (:P)

Comment: @Oshawott the error was "syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION" according to error logs, I can't remember which one that was, it was hours/many attempts ago D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['position'] == $b['position']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['position'] < $b['position']) ? -1 : 1;
}


usort($page, "cmp");
```

Comment: Don't simply say "doesn't seem to work"! Show what you're actually getting, and give us some idea what you expect

Comment: Disregard that, it did work (Didn't notice $pages was supposed to be $page)! Thanks so much, now i can stop tearing my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the code below here: [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8873e9c8bd3ebe0b0efd247d795427d06e2b027f)

**Code**

```
function intComparator($key) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        if ($a[$key] == $b[$key]) return 0;
        return $a[$key] > $b[$key] ? 1 : -1;
    };
}

$items = Array (
  Array (
    'position'   => 0,
    'text'       => 'Home',
    'url'        => './',
    'navigation' => True
  ),
  Array (
    'position'   => 0,
    'text'       => '404',
    'url'        => './?p=404',
    'navigation' => False
  ),
  Array (
    'position'   => 0,
    'text'       => '403',
    'url'        => './?p=403',
    'navigation' => False
  ),
  Array (
    'position'   => 1,
    'text'       => 'Posts',
    'url'        => './?p=posts',
    'navigation' => True
  ),
  Array (
    'position'   => 3,
    'text'       => 'Users',
    'url'        => './?p=users',
    'navigation' => True
  ),
  Array (
    'position'   => 1,
    'text'       => 'Logout',
    'url'        => './?p=logout',
    'navigation' => False
  ),
  Array (
    'position'   => 2,
    'text'       => 'Banner',
    'url'        => './?p=banner',
    'navigation' => True
  ),
  Array (
    'position'   => 5,
    'text'       => 'Login',
    'url'        => './?p=login',
    'navigation' => False
  )
);

usort($items, intComparator('position'));

for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {  
  echo "######## Item $i ########\n";
  $item = $items[$i];          
  foreach($item as $key => $value) {
    printf("%-12s=> %s\n", $key, $value);
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
######## Item 0 ########
position    => 0
text        => Home
url         => ./
navigation  => 1
######## Item 1 ########
position    => 0
text        => 403
url         => ./?p=403
navigation  => 
######## Item 2 ########
position    => 0
text        => 404
url         => ./?p=404
navigation  => 
######## Item 3 ########
position    => 1
text        => Logout
url         => ./?p=logout
navigation  => 
######## Item 4 ########
position    => 1
text        => Posts
url         => ./?p=posts
navigation  => 1
######## Item 5 ########
position    => 2
text        => Banner
url         => ./?p=banner
navigation  => 1
######## Item 6 ########
position    => 3
text        => Users
url         => ./?p=users
navigation  => 1
######## Item 7 ########
position    => 5
text        => Login
url         => ./?p=login
navigation  =>
```